# Simple ternary operator

Tags: javascript

```
 var args = {VehicleManipulation:[{
                        'a:Amount':[Amount],
                        'a:Comment':[Comment],
                        'a:Date':[date],
                        'a:DispatchingVehicleManipulationReasonID':[ReasonID],
                        'a:Distance':[Distance],
                     frEndTime? 'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime':[frEndTime], :'', 
                        'a:FirstDeadheadTripStartTime':[frStartTime],
                        'a:SecondDeadheadTripEndTime':[secondEndTime],
                        'a:SecondDeadheadTripStartTime':[secondStartTime],
                        'a:SubsystemID':[SubsystemNO],
                        'a:VehicleID':[VehicleID],
                        'a:VehicleManipulationID':[VehicleManipulationID],
                        'a:VehicleName':[VehicleName],
        }]};
```

How to put ternary operator to my example?

if variable has value put this line of code 'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime':[frEndTime],
if not do not put anything

now I have syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You need the property first. And then the conditional operator.

```
'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime': frEndTime ? [frEndTime] : '',
```

> if frEndTime dont have value I do not want to put 'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime'

Then you could use another object with a spreading object (if possible)

```
'a:Distance':[Distance],
...(frEndTime ? { 'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime': [frEndTime] } : {}),
'a:FirstDeadheadTripStartTime':[frStartTime],
```

Comment: if frEndTime dont have value I do not  want to put 'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing key in your object which is incorrect. You need to do:

```
  var args = {
  VehicleManipulation: [{
    'a:Amount': [Amount],
    'a:Comment': [Comment],
    'a:Date': [date],
    'a:DispatchingVehicleManipulationReasonID': [ReasonID],
    'a:Distance': [Distance],
    'a:FirstDeadheadTripStartTime': [frStartTime],
    'a:SecondDeadheadTripEndTime': [secondEndTime],
    'a:SecondDeadheadTripStartTime': [secondStartTime],
    'a:SubsystemID': [SubsystemNO],
    'a:VehicleID': [VehicleID],
    'a:VehicleManipulationID': [VehicleManipulationID],
    'a:VehicleName': [VehicleName],
  }]
};
if(frEndTime){
  args.VehicleManipulation[0]['a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime'] = frEndTime
}
```

Doing this will only add the key `a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime` if `frEndTime` value exist.

Comment: how to not add key?

Comment: Using this code will add the key `'a:FirstDeadheadTripEndTime'` only when `frEndTime` is defined